# idea gradle project can't resolve dependency correctily

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url "https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public"
  }
}
dependencies{
  compile('com.alibaba:easyexcel:1.1.2-beta2')
  compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.0.0'
  ...
}
```

In gradle view dependency looks like this. I just add this two dependency to implement excel operation but i can't.

[idea gradle view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pl7H.png)

Comment: No cached version of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.0.4.RELEASE available for offline mode.   ''''  After i changed the repo url ,this error occured

Answer (score 0):

go to settings gradle, uncheck 'offline work'